# Aggregation of absolute values in ElasticSeach

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write query to aggregate absolute values in Elasticsearch. For example, aggregation of absolute values of the field `grade`:

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "avg_grade" : { "avg" : { "field" : "grade" } }
   }
```

}
This computes the average of numeric values in `grade` like this:

```
{
...

"aggregations": {
    "avg_grade": {
        "value": 75
     }
  }
}
```

How to include `abs(grade)` to cater for negative `grade`

Comment: Please explain what results you're currently getting and what results you're expecting instead. Any way for people to recreate your problem is a good step towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 solutions:

- Use transform  script in mappings to make your values positive https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html
- Use scripted  aggregation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html